# toggle class and visibility, display

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

If I also want to toggle the display block: none.

How do I do this

```
$('.exp').on('click', function() {
"use strict";
$(this).toggleClass("plus_sign minus_sign");    
$(this).toggleClass("plus01 minus01");
});
```

The plus_sign and minus sign classes each have an image to indicate the plus and the minus. As the classes toggle, if the class is minus_sign I want the minus image to show. If the class is plus_sign I want the plus image to show and the minus image to hide. The images are background images in the CSS.

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific...what exactly do you want to hide/show?

Comment: No problem will add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it too difficult.

First, set all `.exp` elements to use the plus sign (if the default is to show the plus). Then toggle a class that switches the class so the minus is show. Here's some quick code, which should get you there...

```
$('.exp').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hide_plus');
});
```

Your CSS will be something like this:

```
.exp {
    background:url(/path/to/plus.gif);
}
.hide_plus {
    background:url(/path/to/minus.gif);
}
```

BTW, you're better off using a sprite for these icons and then shifting the position of the background image. Or use something like fontawesome.

Here's a rough fiddle with the +/- toggling without images. Adding the images shouldn't be too difficult.

https://jsfiddle.net/tycahill/1pwbuvga/

Comment: Thanks for that I'll give it a try. Appreciate the help

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to toggle the display of content, too. It's not too pretty--I threw it together really quick. :-)

Comment: Thanks the help from you all makes me understand how to approach things and become a better coder :-)

Answer (score 0):

its very simple you can refer my Plunker please check here i made a simple one for you

```
 $("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#clickme").toggleClass("fa-minus");
});
```

and HTML

```
  <ul class="main-menu">

    <li data-ui-sref-active="active" class="cursor-pointer">
        <a data-ui-sref="dashboard.campaign" href="#/dashboard/campaign"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" id="clickme"></i><span>click me </span></a>
    </li>      

</ul>
```

for reference http://plnkr.co/edit/fZ9AQCrO7RAK8wshQsQX?p=info